# Copy big or small values to $\LaTeX$

Tags: latex

When I create a DistributionFitTest of a distribution I receive very low P values, e.g. $2.456750213008007 \times 10^{-367}$. When I copy this (by right clicking and copy to $\LaTeX$), and insert it in my $\LaTeX$ document, I receive  the number as

```
\text{2.4567502130080068515188263453399491266$\grave{ }$15.778498511135323*${}^{\wedge}$-367}
```

Where as I would prefer to receive a rounded value such as:

```
\text{2.457} \times 10^{-367}
```

Or at least receive an output equivalent, so that I don't have round up manually or edit "*" to "\times", or add up "10".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ScientificForm[
  2.4567502130080068515188263453399491266`15.778498511135323*^-367, 
  4] // TeXForm
```

> 2.457\times 10^{-367}